# Spring Boot/Intellij Resource not loading from src/main/resources folder

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

Spring Boot - 1.4.1;
IDE - IntelliJ 2016.3.EAP

I am trying to load resource like below;

```
f = new File("src/main/resources/PROD_SiteMinder.properties");
```

and

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","src/main/resources/BETA_StagingNewCert.jks");
```

Both these are working fine when I run the app from IDE, but its not working when I try to build the app as war and deploy it on Tomcat.

Could someone please help me out how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using maven? Inside the war file there is no src/main/resources therefore it's not been found. See this: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html for example. Furthermore when you are using spring, why not using `ClassPathResource` instead of `File`?

Comment: @Daniel - Thanks for you response.

Comment: @Daniel - Yes I am using maven and this way was working fine for me for long time. I think I updated something and I don't remember what I did, now its now working. I will check the info you have provided, thanks again.

Comment: In IntelliJ you can make use of the exploded-war file which also contains the resources folder for quick testing. Perhaps you've used this before? Although it's not meant to be productive as far as I know. See this for further information https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Why not use a [`ClassPathResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-implementations-classpathresource)?

Comment: Thanks guys, ClassPathResource helped me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want to load "src/..." from production code. The source won't be available at runtime. Typically, one would load from the classpath (anything in src/main/resources will be copied and available at the root of the classpath -- `new File("PROD_SiteMinder.properties")`

That said, if you are using Spring, prefer `ClassPathResource` over `new File(...)`.

Good luck.